# Как изменить размер изображений?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ли возможность с помощью события the_content поменять размер выводимых изображений в записях?
Или как ещё можно поменять размер изображений в уже существующих записях?
т.е. размер всех вставленных в запись изображений.
the_post_thumbnail('large') меняет размер только у миниатюр записи, а нужно изменять размер всех изображений записи

Comment: идеи есть как это сделать?

Comment: А если в самой верстке (представление) добавить на img атрибуты width и height. Самый простой вариант.

Comment: @Алексей Немцов, нет, нужно именно средствами вордпресс доставать из базы нужный размер, т.к. по умолчанию выводятся маленькие, не чёткие изображения. С помощью css-не получится

Comment: Кажется, в самом WP в настройках media есть конфигурирование размеров изображений. Settings >> Media

Comment: @Алексей Немцов, это настройки при загрузке изображений в бд, это совсем другое. Нужно изменять размер уже существующих изображений

Comment: кто подскажет ?